# How to avoid keyboard unfocused when user write something more than the EditText's height in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Keyboard loses focus on EditTex when I enter some inputs more than 2 lines. Actually, EditText has 2 lines according to it's height in my xml file. I used **android:focusable="true"** and **android:focusableInTouchMode="true"** but they did not solve my problem. How can I avoid this problem ?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/NewsFeedLineGray"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1136" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="88"
    android:background="@drawable/nav_bar_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="88" >

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="24" />

    <!-- Action Bar image+text -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="42" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/commentsActionBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="@string/comments"
            android:textColor="@color/White"
            android:textSize="@dimen/action_bar_text_size" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/backButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
            android:layout_weight="42"
            android:src="@drawable/back_button" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="22" />
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/commentListView"
    style="@style/list_view_divider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="948"
    android:background="@color/NewsFeedLineGray"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" >
</ListView>

<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="20" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="56"
    android:background="@color/NewsFeedLineGray"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="640" >

    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="20" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/commentEditText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="444"
        android:background="@color/White"
        android:maxLength="200"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/comment_text_size" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="20" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/sendCommentButton"
        style="@style/button_type"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="136"
        android:text="@string/send"
        android:textSize="@dimen/comment_button_text_size" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="20" />
</LinearLayout>

<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="20" />
```

**Before enter 2 lines**
[image: Before enter 2 lines]

**After enter 2 lines. Keyboard loses focus when I start to write on 3rd line**
[image: After enter 2 lines]

Comment: have you tried setting a scrollbar for the Edittext? Vertical maybe, so when data get extended the scrolls got enabled instead of the editText stretched `android:scrollbars="vertical"` (if i got what you mean right)

Comment: I editted my question with images. Now, you can understand clearly my friend @Yazan.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to hide the Keyboad,

```
EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);  
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: I want to continue to work with keyboard when user enters more than EditText's height not hide the keyboard.

Comment: mean after you write the 2 lines in edittext then automatically keyboard should be disappeared ?

Comment: Keyboard should **not** be **disappeared** but it automatically closes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set different properties to your `EditText` view.

You can try

```
    setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NONE);
    setInputType(EditorInfo.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
    setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
    setSingleLine(false);
    setLines(<any number>);
```

Comment: @smihilor, I realized you also need a couple of different methods. Please take a look at my updated response.

Comment: I tried but it does not work. I guess that it is related with weight.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:singleLine="true"

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/commentEditText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="444"
    android:background="@color/White"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:maxLength="200"
    android:textColor="@color/Black"
    android:textSize="@dimen/comment_text_size" />
```

Comment: I don't wanna use single line @David. User can write 200 characters in to the Comment EditText in my application. Keyboard loses focus on EditText after enter 2 lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText yourEditText = (EditText ) findViewById(R.id.myTextViewId);
yourEditText.requestFocus();
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)    getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(yourEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

Comment: Thanks @David. I edit my question. Your answer helps person to keep keyboard  on screen continuously. I can not expand EditText because I gave a weight to EditText so keyboard loses focus.